Pytest tests failing because autoincrement primary key is not reset in function level test fixtures
I am trying to write endpoint tests using FastAPI, Pytest, SQLalchemy, Postgres and Pants.
I have a common conftest.py file that looks like:
@fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def create_tables():
    try:
        Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
        yield
    finally:
        Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)


@fixture(scope="function", name="_db_session")
def fixture_db_session():
    """Create a new session for each test case."""
    try:
        connection = engine.connect()
        transaction = connection.begin()
        session = SessionLocal(bind=connection)
        yield session
    finally:
        session.close()
        transaction.rollback()
        connection.close()

@fixture(scope="function", name="_populate_nodes")
def fixture_populate_nodes(_db_session):
    """Populate the nodes table with sample data."""
    sample_data = [
        {
            "title": "Node 1",
            "logo": "logo1.jpg",
            "seo_description": "SEO description for Node 1",
        },
        {
            "title": "Node 2",
            "logo": "logo2.jpg",
            "seo_description": "SEO description for Node 2",
        },
    ]
    for data in sample_data:
        node = Nodes(**data)
        _db_session.add(node)
    _db_session.commit()

And a service level conftest.py file that looks like:
@fixture(scope="function")
def test_client(_db_session):
    """Create a test client that uses the override_get_db fixture to return a session."""
    def override_get_db():
        try:
            yield _db_session
        finally:
            _db_session.close()
    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db
    with TestClient(app) as test_client:
        yield test_client

And my tests look like:
# Test get_node endpoint
def test_get_node(test_client, _populate_nodes):
    """Test get_node endpoint."""
    response = test_client.get("/nodes/1")
    assert response.status_code == 200


# Test get_nodes endpoint
def test_get_nodes(test_client, _populate_nodes):
    """Test get_nodes endpoint."""
    response = test_client.get("/nodes/?node_ids=1&node_ids=2")
    assert response.status_code == 200


# Test create_node endpoint
def test_create_node(test_client, _populate_nodes):
    """Test create_node endpoint."""
    print("I am here => test_create_node")
    node_data = {
        "title": "Test Node 1",
        "logo": None,
        "seo_description": None,
    }
    response = test_client.post("/nodes/", json=node_data)
    assert response.status_code == 200


# Test update_node endpoint
def test_update_node(test_client, _populate_nodes):
    """Test update_node endpoint."""
    node_data = {"title": "Updated Node"}
    response = test_client.patch("/nodes/1/", json=node_data)
    assert response.status_code == 200


# Test update_nodes endpoint
def test_update_nodes(test_client, _populate_nodes):
    """Test update_nodes endpoint."""
    node_data = {"title": "Updated Node"}
    response = test_client.patch("/nodes/?node_ids=1", json=node_data)
    assert response.status_code == 200


# Test delete_node endpoint
def test_delete_node(test_client, _populate_nodes):
    """Test delete_node endpoint."""
    response = test_client.delete("/nodes/1/")
    assert response.status_code == 200


# Test delete_nodes endpoint
def test_delete_nodes(test_client, _populate_nodes):
    """Test delete_nodes endpoint."""
    response = test_client.delete("/nodes/?node_ids=1&node_ids=2&node_ids=3")
    assert response.status_code == 200

From what I've investigated, what is happening is at the start of each function being tested, the _populate_nodes fixture runs correctly and adds 2 nodes to the test database and at the end of the function being tested the data is removed as well. However the primary key that is autoincrement keeps on increasing. So the 2 nodes added on the first test that runs will have ids 1 and 2 but the second one will have ids 3 and 4. This causes and issue since my tests are based on the assumption that a completely new environment will be set from scratch. Would appreciate both a solution for this issue as well as any general improvements / suggestions anyone has. Thank you.
Update:
After trying out the solution suggested by MatsLindh I've discovered a bigger issue in my testing environment, that I've added in the comments. Don't need a solution for the autoincrementing ids issue now, I guess. But if anyone has any suggestions on improving testing structure feel free to comment.

Have your _populate_nodes fixture return the generated ids - you can then access them  from the _populated_nodes argument in your function - that will also make your tests properly independent of whether they run by themselves, the sequence they run in and other parts - you get the generated ids back, and avoid the temporal coupling and pre-existing state of the database.

So I tried this and it helped me realize that my issue is bigger than the auto-incrementing ids. Because now tests pass correctly when they are run one file at a time using "pants test <file_name>" but when I run them at the same time with "pants test ::", they fail because of errors like table does not exist or duplicate key value violates unique constraint. I guess I'll need to revisit how I've gone about laying the base structure for testing. Thanks for your answer though, it helped identify the bigger issue.
